# Error with jquery BlockUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, blockui, jquery-blockui

I've used this plugin many times, in very much the same manner as seen here, and yet my latest implementation is not working.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.blockUI.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function disableButtons(){
        alert('TEST'); //this is here just to see if the function is called
        $('div.blockbutton').block({
            message: '<h4>Saving...</h4>',
            css: { border: '2px solid orange' }
         });
     }
</script>
```

And the HTML:

```
<div align="center" class="blockbutton">
    <input name="save" type="button" class="btn6022" value="Save" 
       onClick=disableButtons();
         <c:if test='${(sessionScope.package != "NWR")}'>                        
       saveConfirm1(onset_date,report_date,lost_consciousness_date,fatal_death_date);">
         </c:if>
         <c:if test='${(sessionScope.package == "NWR")}'>                        
       "saveConfirm2(onset_date,report_date,fatal_death_date);">
          </c:if>
     </div>
```

Here is what my Firebug console is giving me when triggering the function:
TypeError: $(...).block is not a function
[Break On This Error]

css: { border: '2px solid orange' }

I'm baffled since this code is identical to what I have done on other pages, without fail. Can someone spot a problem here I'm missing?

Comment: After posting my answer, I realized what you may be trying to do. Are you trying to call both disableButtons() and saveConfirm1/2 onClick?

Comment: That is correct, I'm calling them both. disableButtons() IS getting called, since the alert is popping up that I put in as a test, but the rest of the function fails and therefore fails also to call the saveConfirm1/2 function.

Answer (score 0):

I see some inconsistencies within your `<c:if>` blocks. The bottom one wraps saveConfirm2 in double quotes. The top one only has a double quote at the end after saveConfirm. Even without that issue, it's not completely clear what you are trying to do, so just take a look at the rendered HTML to make sure it makes sense. Also, I'm not familiar, but it looks to be JSP from a quick search. In that case, the `<c:if>` blocks are just for conditional rendering. The content inside those blocks should end in `/>` to close the `<input` node. In order to close the node correctly and for both of your functions to get called onClick, you need to have the modifications below. I made the onClick start with a double quote.  Then the content in the c:if blocks closes the initial opening quote and closes the

```
   onClick="disableButtons();
     <c:if test='${(sessionScope.package != "NWR")}'>                        
   saveConfirm1(onset_date,report_date,lost_consciousness_date,fatal_death_date);" />
     </c:if>
     <c:if test='${(sessionScope.package == "NWR")}'>                        
   saveConfirm2(onset_date,report_date,fatal_death_date);" />
      </c:if>
```

I think you were seeing the javascript errors due to malformed HTML.

Comment: I tried this, but it makes no difference. The disableButtons() function is working but fails (apparently due to the .block function not working -- which it should, since the jquery.blockUI.js file is included. Again, this works fine on all other files I've put this in, just not this one.

Comment: I'm wondering if the function isn't failing due to the malformed HTML.  I have seen it happen, but I'm not completely sure it will fix it in your case.  If so, good luck finding a solution. I'm sure you've triple checked that your libraries are being properly included, but aside from that I don't have other ideas as to what would cause this.

Comment: I suspected the HTML could have been the problem, but if I simply remove the disableButtons() function, everything works as it should.

Comment: I tried something very similar to what you have. The rendered HTML is: `<div align="center" class="blockbutton"><input name="save" type="button" class="btn6022" value="Save" onClick="disableButtons(); testfunc2();" /></div>`. The function gets properly called and the nice BlockUI interface displays. Are you sure you are not getting a 404 or the like on either of the two script resources? It worked for me without changing much except that I just had the final rendered HTML in my source file.

Comment: No 404's -- I'm not sure what is going on -- just one of the universe's unexplained mysteries.

Answer (score 0):

$.browser was removed in 1.9.1
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-blockui-plugin-broken-with-jq-1-9-1